# How To Sort List In Ascending Order After AddRange

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Here I am trying to sort list in `Ascending Order` after `AddRange`, I have a list where at `0 index` i.e `[0]` there is data with `MessageId=20` and at `1 index` i.e `[1]` there is data with `MessageId=19`.
Now what I want is to sort the list in `ascending order` based on that `MessageId`.For this I have used `OrderBy(x => x.MessageId)`.
But the problem is that even after using `OrderBy(x => x.MessageId)` list is not sorted in ascending order basedon MessageId.

Any help will be grate.Thank you

Below is what I have done to sort

```
messagesList.AddRange(MsgList);
messagesList.OrderBy(x => x.MessageId).ToList();
```

Comment: `LINQ` will not modify the source (although each item can be modified by side-effect). You need to set your `messageList` to the new list it creates. In that case, you should not use `AddRange`, instead use `Concat` like this `messageList = messageList.Concat(MsgList).OrderBy(e => e.MessageId).ToList()`

Comment: @KingKing Thank you for  the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ToList() Method Return List ; you need Set result of Ordering.
like this :

```
messagesList = messagesList.OrderBy(x => x.MessageId).ToList();
```